# Google Spreadsheet Dynamic Column Array

Tags: google-sheets

I am finding it difficult to use array formula when I insert new columns. I want to make it divisible when I displace the column.

Ex.
I have used array formula in Sheet1 in column C. If I add a new column before column C, I want that my formula should change to new column C/column B(which was C earlier)

```
Ex dataset with 2 column A and B  
A has n values   
B has n values  
C=arrayformula(iferror(B/A-1,0))  
If i insert new column before column C   
C has n values  
D=arrayformula(iferror(C/B-1,0))
```

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lzeVAk5fIZbSL5q0LKm7ZQKleS6tB31G8SIw2nGYhsU/edit#gid=743953923

Comment: Why is it difficult, what's the error? Also your sheet is not public

Comment: The error is that I have to formulate my task and I am finding it difficult that I have to manually change the formulas every day. Given public access

Answer (score 0):

You can use offset for this

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(OFFSET(C1:C, 0, -1) / OFFSET(C1:C, 0, -2) - 1, 0))
```

Comment: Not working can you help me with the execution. Your answer is dependent on the column C. Can you help me to overcome this problem and use just one formula and not two

Comment: It is dependent on the column the formula is in which will change to D when you insert a new column to the left. How is this not working as the formula does what you described you wanted